# Does Rscript on Linux take a snapshot of the file before executing the script?

Tags: r, linux

If I use the shell command `Rscript MyFile.R` to run my rscript, and then, while it is running, I change and save `MyFile.R`, will the rscript execute based on the file at the time of execution?  Or does it read one line at a time of the file and execute the updated file?

Comment: You could try and find out.... something like `cat('start'); Sys.sleep(60); cat('end')` ought to give you plenty of time to edit the last line after running the script.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Post as answer? It doesn't seem like it needs any more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file is being read line-by-line, so **it is not safe to edit the source file while it is being executed by R**. Technically, `Rscript` executes `R --file`, the reading of the input is then implemented in platform-dependent code. On Unix, the input is read using `fgets`, line-by-line, when a file was given.

Whether and when R will actually read the modified source file depends on the OS (buffering by the I/O library, should be line-by-line) and on the editor (e.g. if the editor lets the user edit a copy of the file and then rename at the end, R will keep reading the old file). I can observe both behaviours (changes edited in `joe` not impacting execution, changes appended by `cat` impacting execution).